# Window on top of fullscreen - raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mplayer, flir

i tried to force my window to stay on top. But it isn't work properly for me. Im working on raspbian and im trying to open MPlayer window above magicmirror fullscreen.

I tried it with command

```
wmctrl -r MPlayer -b add,above
```

same as clicking on the header and choose "*always on top*" .

It works ok with other windowed apps, not with fullscreen MM app.

P.S. Magic mirror app always autostart with fullscreen and it has to stay like that. Im trying to force MPlayer window above fullscreen. MPlayer opens camera flir source. It opens for 20 sec (for view), making measurements and then close.

Maybe you have some ideas how to help me?